# Documentation for implementing a Java based Red5 RTMPClient?

Tags: java, audio-streaming, red5, rtmp

I'm investigating implementing an RTMP client in Java to do audio conferencing with Red5. There's an `RTMPClient` and related classes that look like they can be used. However, the implementation seems to be based on a delegate pattern with multiple other classes involved, which is difficult to decipher without docs.

Anyone have any pointers for documentation in this area?

Answer (score 0):

[The Red5 Reference Manual](http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/UsersReferenceManual)

[Helpfiles and Tutorials](http://osflash.org/red5/help)

[Project and Developer information](http://osflash.org/red5/projectInfo)

[Users mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/red5interest)

[Developers mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/red5developers)

[Google Code project page](http://code.google.com/p/red5/)

[javadocs](http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something higher level. E.g., the `RTMPClient.createStream` method takes an `IPendingServiceCallback` object, which has a `getResult` method that just returns an `Object`. There are several on... methods but it's not clear when they're called. The `publishStreamData` method takes a `streamId` argument but there's no documentation about what value to use. I could go on, but basically it's a complex API and bare Javadocs just aren't sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't found concise documentation in the above yet. I'm working through the dev mailing list and the source. I'll post a summary with I've got enough info for audio streaming.

Comment: Have you tried with Red5 dev mailing list, GrepCode to get some input?
Yes, it is very poor documentation wiht RTMP client and other Red5 api.  I found some thing helpful is red5 mailing list.